# How to Convert JSON with dynamic keys with ObjectMapper?

Tags: json, swift, dynamic, key

I'm currently using ObjectMapper for Swift for mapping JSON Object from API to model Object

My api returns a JSON like this:

```
{
  "tracks": {
        "1322": {
          "id": 1322,
          "gain": 80
        },
        "1323": {
          "id": 1323,
          "gain": 80
        },
        "1324": {
          "id": 1324,
          "gain": 80
        },
        "1325": {
          "id": 1325,
          "gain": 80
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the normal mapping, it is the "key" of each "track" is the id of itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to select something without either using indexes or a hard coded key.

But for your case, you might be able to do this:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["0.id"]
    gain <- map["0.gain"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar thing, this is my JSON:

```
{
    "goals": {
        "total": 0,
        "ecpa": 0,
        "data": {
            "575afbdca5a101e3088b2b6554398b0c": {
                "volume": 1,
                "ecpa": 4,
                "coa": "5.00"
            },
            "575afbdca5a101e3088b2b6554398frt": {
                "volume": 3,
                "ecpa": 1,
                "coa": "1.00"
            }

        }
    }
 }
```

This is StatsGoal class that implements Mappable protocol

```
import ObjectMapper

class StatsGoal: Mappable {
    var total: Double?
    var ecpa: Double?
    var data: [String : StatsGoalData]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        total   <- map["total"]
        ecpa    <- map["ecpa"]
        data    <- map["data"]
    }
}
```

And this is StatsGoalData that implements Mappable protocol and is used as class property (child object) in StatsGoal class

```
import ObjectMapper

class StatsGoalData: Mappable {
    var volume: Double?
    var ecpa: Double?
    var coa: Double?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        volume  <- map["volume"]
        ecpa    <- map["ecpa"]
        coa     <- map["coa"]
    }
}
```

and this is how you can iterate over data property after mapping

```
    for element in stats {
        let data = element.goals?.data
        for statsGoalData in data! {
            let statsGoalDataElement = statsGoalData.1
                print(statsGoalDataElement.ecpa!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if the "data" object is an JSON Array in the JSON response? How to handle that?